# Issue Related to Formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have database of students.. I have generated Student Exam Report with Marks and PassNumber
as displayed in Following Image

[image]

Report had grouping field Group by Date and ExamNumbers there may be 20 pages in current report, each group displays on New Page.

Now i just want to displays name who are TOP 3 rankers among Passnumber field.

how can i do it using formula Field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally suppress the details section for students with passnumbers > 3.

Go to the Select Expert for the Details section and add this as a conditional suppression formula: `{table.pass_number}>3`. This will prevent all but the top 3 (including ties) from being displayed on the report.

Edit: If you just want to display the names of the top 3 students in the GF, you can add them to an array in the details section while processing the report. To do this you'll need to create a formula in the GH that declares/reinitializes the array, a formula in the details section that checks the pass number and puts it into the array if less than or equal to 3 (since there can be ties, this will get a little tricky and you will have to resize the array if necessary). Finally, in the GF you can display the array with a third formula that joins the array's elements together via `join(myarray,', ');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but i want to display top 3 ranker's name in Footer.. above Report(displays in IMage) is ok... but i want to display name of ranker in footer, how can i?

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani See my edit. Basically, just add the names to an array in the details section, then display them in the group footer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the Group Sort Expert feature to do this. However I read a [forum post](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=563625&sid=39866a6eb60d17e41ac8ea9300bf5fe4) indicating how to make sure that option is enabled. Hope it helps.